# Possible reasons for forcing OutOfMemory error in Java

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I was just reading about OutOfMemory errors. I understand a statement like:

```
int[] i = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
```

would throw an OutOfMemory error. My question is, is there any scenario where a programmer would actually want to force such an error (e.g. testing)? If so, what could it be?

I would be glad if someone answered my question? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be any number of reasons to force an out of memory error. Evil hackers learn to do things like that to get code to break and allow access.  Security people would do this in test cases to harden the code being tested and to fix vulnerabilities.

OS developers could do this kind of testing to improve the stability of systems and recover from bad software. Blue screen of death anyone?

If memory is an issue in certain instances, such as embedded code or micro computers in satellites, etc., this type of testing would give you development parameters for code and data sizing.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons you might like to explicitly throw such an exception include

- testing
- exiting early when you know something is not going to succeed.
- provide a more useful error message

In those cases you might have:

```
List<Foo> getManyFoos(int nToGet) {
  if(nToGet * sizeOfAFoo > availableSpareMemory)
    throw new OutOfMemoryError("Too many foos requested")
  ...
}
```

Cases where you might want to catch it would be where you're allocating a cache (and the size doesn't matter overly much)

```
List<Foo> createCache() {
  try {
    List<Foo> bigCache = getManyFoos(1000);
    return bigCache;
  } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
    return getManyFoos(10);
  }
}
```

or you might expect the request to succeed after a GC.

```
Foo[] getFoosArray(int lotsOfFoos) {
  try {
    return new Foo[lotsOfFoos];
  } catch( OutOfMemoryError e ) {
    System.gc();
    return new Foo[lotsOfFoos];
  }
}
```